# Ajax Submit form without reload the page is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, form-submit, form-serialize

I'm trying to submit a form without reloading the page with Ajax but i had no success till now, it still reloads the page. On the index.php I have this code below. Could someone help?

```
<?php 
# form code
?>

<div>
  <form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off" id="theForm">
    <button type="submit" name="SeguA" />
      Seguir
    </button> 
  </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#theForm').submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var form = $(this);
      $.ajax({
        type: form.attr('method'),
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize()
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: If you open the dev tools, do you see any errors? (F12)

Comment: @KevinB Actually not.

Comment: Your button is incorrectly closed, is that related?

Comment: @KevinB This take no changes.

Comment: I don't see anything else wrong. Is this a direct copy paste? id's all match? are the dev tools set to show both errors and info logs? Do you have preserve logs enabled so that errors aren't deleted when the form submits?

Comment: well, bsides the missing jquery include, but i kinda assumed you've got that somewhere.

Comment: Changing the button type to "button" instead of "submit" may work a lot better: `<button type="button" name="SeguA" />`

Comment: ... Changing it to type button would stop it from submitting the form... that's a bad idea.

Comment: do you submit form by hitting enter key or the click event on submit button? If you are using enter key it might need to be taken care with `keyCode`

Comment: That is also irrelevant; regardless of how you submit the form, it will trigger the submit event. The only exception would be if  you submitted the form via the `form.submit` method programmatically.

Comment: @AnirudhMangalvedhekar I'm using the click event

Comment: @Jeremy This still reloads the page

Answer (score 1):

This is not meant as a "solution" in the direct sense of the word, but as a demonstration, that your code actually works in the version you posted it. I only added the two `<input>` elements and the `console.log()` line.

So, maybe the problem is somewhere outside the code you posted here?

```js
$('#theForm').submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var form = $(this);
      console.log(form.serialize());
      $.ajax({
        type: form.attr('method'),
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize()
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off" id="theForm">
    <input type="text" name="a" value="some">
    <input type="text" name="b" value="thing">
    <button type="submit" name="SeguA" />
      Seguir
    </button> 
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe it's because i'm using bootstrap? Could you try?